# Linq split comma , convert int and keep in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to use linq in my project.

So i have a question about split and keep list by using linq.

I have Id values as a string.

**"1","2","3","4"**

I can see above Id values in **item.StringIdValues**

I need to split as comma Id values after that i want to convert to int32 and match UserId.

```
foreach (var item in MyDatas)
{
var Something = item.StringValues; 
int FilteredId == // I want to split as comma and convert values to int32.
var result=context.Users.Any(s=>s.UserId==FilteredId).select(s>s.UserName).firstordefault();
//Than Keep above result Id's in list.

List<Something>=result;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It has string Id values next to next "1","2" etc..

Answer (score 2):

You need to split then parse, then select:

```
List<int> numericItems = item.StringIdValues
    .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList()
```

To match the userID, do:

```
int FilteredId = item.StringIdValues
    .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
    .First(i => i == UserId);
```

You might want to change it to `FirstOrDefault` and null check it if the `UserId` may not be present in the list.